# Read file from 1688 url using CURL

Tags: php, curl

I have link from 1688.com: https://qr.1688.com/share.html?secret=FGhiwaK6, which i want to read content from.
I get the right content while using this tool: https://reqbin.com/c-p0iw9eho
But I cannot get this if using the following PHP snippet:

```
<?php
    $url = "https://qr.1688.com/share.html?secret=FGhiwaK6";
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    var_dump($resp);
?>
```

Please help.

Comment: The content must be:

Comment: What's the exact problem? What have you tried to debug and resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a useragent for this to work. Change your code to something like:

```
<?php
$url = "https://qr.1688.com/share.html?secret=FGhiwaK6";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
```

Comment: I use your code and the result is in: https://2fly.com.vn/test.php. The right content must be in https://reqbin.com/c-p0iw9eho when you click [Run] button.

Comment: That _is_ the correct output you get when you `var_dump($resp);`. If you want just the string use `echo $resp;`